# Beautiful Soup returning empty list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

tickersymbol = 'A'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+tickersymbol+'p='+tickersymbol 

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode('utf-8') 
page = soup(htmltext, "html.parser")
price = page.find_all('<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"><!-- react-text: 331 -->(.+?)<!-- /react-text --></span>x')
print(price)
```

This returns an empty list while it should return the stock's price which should be where the '(.+?)' is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe the content of that page is generated dynamically. Did you check the output returned by `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`?

Comment: Try `page.find_all("span", class_ = "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")`

Comment: @StegSchreck I think you are right, do you know the best way to convert dynamic content to static html on mac os?

Comment: You might want to have a look at selenium. You basically need a browser in order to let it render the dynamical content. E.g. with the headless phantomjs webdriver.